# osTicket with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, ticket-system

I wish to have osTicket like functionality with CakePHP. More on where customers email to a certain support email address and CakePHP will periodically retrieve emails (not sure how?) and then create unique tickets out of it.

Each ticket will then be assigned an unique ID and replies to and from customer should be grouped into the correct ticket ID.

From the way I see it, it is this manner:

CakePHP checks inbox using IMAP/POP3
Gets unread email list
Look through the list for existing IDs, new emails with no ID will be created as new tickets
Support team will reply via web admin interface

I am not sure if the above makes sense. I was hoping to just take osTicket and integrate it to CakePHP if it is not too hard.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds like you want something like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6319961/receiving-retrieving-email-in-cakephp

Comment: I am able to get emails using the plugin in the link above. But now I have problems getting threaded emails and the body of the email is encoded to a certain format when emails are sent from a gmail server.

Is there a standard way to decode it or I need to check where it is coming from?

Answer (score 0):

What you already said is right.

> CakePHP checks inbox using IMAP/POP3 Gets unread email list Look
>   through the list for existing IDs, new emails with no ID will be
>   created as new tickets Support team will reply via web admin interface

Check for new emails, parse the subject if it matches the pattern you need, if yes lookup your database if records for the ticket number from the subject exist and if not create them.

Actually that's a pretty simple task to do with CakePHP. The most "complex" part is about accessing imap/pop3 because the CakePHP does not provide any data sources for that. You can write your own imap/pop3 data source or check if the there is already one somewhere available for free.

Comment: I was able to get the emails through IMAP with the link posted by Dave above. Really nice plugin.